# REST APIs and a front end website - which framework to use?

Tags: angularjs, rest, yeoman, mean.io

over the last 2 months I taught myself Angular JS and ionic and have built a pretty effective iOS and Android client for a specific idea I have in mind. I am now embarking on prototyping a website for myself that this client will talk to.

The website will be pretty simple:
a) I am thinking the front end will be using a responsive bootstrap theme like this one: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

b) The website will have a login function, and after login, allow subscribers to upload 'coupon' - that consists of a name, description and expiry date. This needs to be stored in the DB. I also plan to offer a search and edit functionality via the website

c) Now, I also want the backend to expose a REST API like, say, this form:

```
http://server.com/api/login
http://server.com/api/getAllCoupons
http://server.com/api/getCoupon/id=foo
```

etc

I've been researching various options and have come across:
1) Mean.io
2) Yeoman
3) Strongloop

At this stage, given I am completely new to web development, **and only have an idea of Angular JS and a bit of Node js**, I am confused on what to use

My criteria really is ease of use. I'd like a framework that lets me get up and running with a website and an API connected to it that can get data out of the website DB

Do you have a recommendation on the simplest and quickest way to go about it? I want to continue focusing on my mobile app and need the website to be as painless as possible.

Thank you

Comment: What backend programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: if PHP, I would recommend Symfony or lighter weight "Silex"
if GoLang, I would use Martini
do you know what language you prefer?

Comment: Thanks - I am hoping to use angular-js as the backend as well. Since I've posted, I'm experimenting with the angular-ja-full stack. So far I have a small website up and a connected web service all via angular js